# Only import XML if it has been updated

Tags: ios, core-data, nsurlconnection, nsxmlparser

I'm using NSURLConnection to grab an XML file.   I parse the XML file and then use it to populate Core Data.

If the NSURLConnection fails to connect (i.e. user has no internet connection), I just read the persistent data from Core Data.

However, I'm thinking...  Is there a way that I can do a check on the XML file to see if it has updated from the last time I used it?   So I can save redownloading/repopulating it if is unchanged?

Checking Last Modified on the file or something?

Anyone have a good solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is tagged incorrectly for checking a file modified date on the server. If the server supports it you could send a head request and check the Last-Modified header.

Comment: Anyway you could provide some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by checking the http headers or etags.

Comment: I was able to get the sample code to do this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895451/how-to-get-remote-file-modification-date

Answer (score 0):

Have the server add its current system time to the XML file as a new field like `<timestamp>1332368408</timestamp>`.  You'll need another server API call to check if that particular file has been modified like `http://<server>/xmlFileChangedSince/1332368408` returning true or false, based on the last modified of the file as you suggested or by overwriting the `<timestamp>` field each time the file is modified.  If the result of the above http request is true then your app knows to download the newly modified data.

The benefit to the approach of adding the `<timestamp>` field to the XML file on the server side is that it prevents any necessity of syncing the server and app times which are guaranteed to not by exactly synchronous.  If you don't want to add the field to the XML data then you can set the timestamp of your app-side data based on when the `NSURLConnection` returned but if you want it to be exactly reliable you'll need to sync app and server times.  While this isn't particularly difficult it is an annoyance.