# Settings.plist iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a `Settings.plist` file in my iOS application. I access it using this code below:

```
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.plist"];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path])
    {
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"];

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

But, say I make some changes to the Settings.plist file in my application, like add another row. Then if I publish it, users that already have my app will have an out dated `Settings.plist` file. Any ideas on a workaround or anything? I have tried accessing the `Settings.plist` file straight from the `NSString *bundle`, but then the values don't "save".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a file modification date check, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6895451/171206). Then if the modification date is later than the last checked date, download the Settings.plist file and replace it in the users app.

Comment: But, won't that replace all the user's saved settings to the default settings?